# How can i bring just one data from firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know how to get one data from the list of key

i know the key

but what i want to just get from one data what i saved

i don't understand why it is null

in the value 'petcode' is saved key

[image]

**This is what i trying to get the data petname**

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pets").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child(petcode);


        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                petname = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("petname"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

but when i see the log
petname value is null 
how can i get data from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
ref.child("-LiCZpsymgNgtNcCinpHR5").child("petname").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        try {
            if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "" + snapshot.getValue()); // your name values you will get here
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", " it's null.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.e("onCancelled", " cancelled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnak you Mr.Patel it helped 
but is there no way to get data like String.valueOf()?

Comment: This is the best recommended way to get your values but there is no other workaround if you want to directly fetch a string however if you want your value in string you can easily covert it using .tostring()

Comment: Please consider marking my answer correct if it helped i'll appreciate it!

Comment: sorry i did it 
it was blocked marking cause didn't passed one min TT 
Thank you so much Mr. Patel

Answer (score 0):

```
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pets").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child(petcode).child("petname");
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String petname = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);                       
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                conformDialog.setMessage("Something bad happened!, try again");
                conformDialog.setCancelable(true);
                conformDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            }
        });
```

and do not use **addValueEventListener** for a single event, it will monitor forever